# Converting text to array

Tags: c++, pointers, text, ifstream

I'm writing a function to read a text file into an array as a class object, but the compiler won't allow me to initialize the class object. it gives me the error code,"error: cannot convert 'std::array::value_type {aka BusinessContact}' to "BusinessContact*' in initialization.

The exception is thrown at this line`contact[count ++] = con;`

```
void ReadTransform(array<BusinessContact, maxsize> &contact, int&n)
{
  try
  {
    cout << "\nRead employees from file..." << endl;
    //open the file
    ifstream inFile("Contacts.txt", ios::in);
    if( !inFile )
      throw new string("Contacts.text not opened...");
    //read the file
    int count = 0;
    string firstName, Lastname, phoneNumber, emailAddress, company;
    BusinessContact *con;
    while (inFile>>firstName>> Lastname>> phoneNumber>> emailAddress>> company)
    {
      con = new BusinessContact(firstName, Lastname, phoneNumber, emailAddress, company);
      contact[count ++] = con;
      inFile.ignore();
    }
    for (BusinessContact *c : contact)
    {
      cout << c-> GetfirstName ()     << endl
        << c-> GetlastName()       << endl
        << c-> GetphoneNumber()    << endl
        << c-> GetemailAddress()   << endl
        << c-> Getcompany()        << endl;
    }

    inFile.close();
  }
  catch(string* msg)
  {
    cerr << "Exception: " + *msg << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly the issue he is having; I suspect that when he says exception he means compiler error.

Comment: no it doesn't compile. I can write to the text file, and this is basically the same code. This function is to read only, I don't know what the subtle change I'd need to make to make it compile and work.

Comment: The answer is: **dump the pointers**. I mean `con` and `throw new string` too.

Comment: dumping the pointers gives me a new error. It says I have to overload the equal sign, which also doesn't make sense. I think i need to address in the  parameter arguement though so it'll accept an arguement, not too sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of `BusinessContact` *objects* and you try to populate it with *pointers* to `BusinessContact` objects. Not the same thing.

If you follow [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) all you have to do is assign directly to the entry in the array. Something like

```
contact[count ++] = BusinessContact(firstName, Lastname, phoneNumber, emailAddress, company);;
```

Alternatively and depending on your data, you could actually read directly from the file into the array entry:

```
while (inFile >> contact[count].firstName
              >> contact[count].Lastname
              >> contact[count].phoneNumber
              >> contact[count].emailAddress
              >> contact[count].company)
{
    ++count;
}
```

Or why not overload the input operator, so you can do

```
while (inFile >> contact[count])
    ++count;
```

---

Later when you iterate over the array use constant references, like

```
for (BusinessContact const& c : contact) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

con is of type BusinessContact*. You are tring to insert con into an array of BusinessContact, contact.

Do,

```
contact[count ++] = *con;
```

Comment: `delete con;` after it